# File as argument for Win32 application

Tags: c, winapi

How can I make a Win32 application open a file at startup when calling it like this (e.g. with a shortcut or via command line)?

```
program.exe "document.txt"
```

Comment: Parse the `lpCmdLine` argument passed to `WinMain`, extract the file name, open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) shows how to retrieve command line arguments and turn them into an array of string

Even though it is written in a `main`, it works equally well in `WinMain` or any other function

Comment: I haven't been busy with this for a while. Thanks for the help. Now I have the arguments in an array of `LPWSTR`. But how can I use these values in a message box or convert them to `char*`?

Comment: Do you want to collapse them all into one string, or display/convert each one individually?

Comment: I want to use the filename in `fopen`, but it's an `LPWSTR` and `fopen` requires `char*`. I also want to display the filename in the titlebar using `SetWindowText`.

Comment: Let's say your `LPWSTR` filename is stored using the variable `fileNameW`. The length of the string (including the `NULL`) is found by `size_t length = wcslen(fileNameW);`. The `char*` buffer can then be declared as `char *fileNameA = new char[length];`. Finally, the buffer can be filled using the `wcstombs` function like so: `wcstombs(fileNameA, fileNameW, length);`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Unicode program use `lpCmdLine`, otherwise use `GetCommandLineW` and pass the result to `CommandLineToArgvW` to get a list of strings for the arguments to the program, then it works just like with a command-line program.